# visualforce page not workign as expected

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement where I need to create 2 record types in contacts object called `Big Deal` & `Storefront`.

Now I have to create a picklist field called `Department for a User` and it has 2 values which are `Big Deal` & `Storefront`.

When the user whose picklist value is set to say `Big Deal` logins in to salesforce and opens an account which has contacts of both the record types, the related list (contact) must display only the records of the recordtype with which the user has logges in by setting the picklist value in users.

I've written a standard controller for this and it displays the expected result in the backend but does not work as expected when I tested in the UI.

Please help me. I am a newbie to salesforce.

VF Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myStandardControllerExtension">
    <apex:detail subject="{!Account}" relatedList="false"/> 
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock > 
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!con}" var="c" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(con))}">
                <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!c.phone}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
       </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class myStandardControllerExtension {
    public String accname{get;set;} 
    public List<Contact> con {get;set;} 
    public myStandardControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController acon){
       getRecords(); 
    } 

    public List<Contact> getRecords() {
        User u = [SELECT Department__c FROM User WHERE id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
        String departmentPicklist = u.department__c;
        System.debug('*** User : ' + u);
        RecordType rt = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE name = :departmentPicklist Limit 1];
        List<Contact> con = [Select id,LastName,Name FROM Contact WHERE RecordTypeId = : rt.Id]; 
        System.debug('*** con : ' + con );
        return con;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'M posting below the vf code and the standard controller that i wrote    :-   VF Code :-   <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myStandardControllerExtension">
 <apex:detail subject="{!Account}" relatedList="false"/>
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!con}" var="c" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(con))}">
        <apex:column value="{!c.name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!c.phone}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable> 
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: public class myStandardControllerExtension
{
    public String accname{get;set;}   
    public List<Contact> con {get;set;}
    
    
    public myStandardControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController acon){
          getRecords();    
    }           
    
    public List<Contact> getRecords()
    {
        User u = [SELECT Department__c
                  FROM User 
                  WHERE id=:userinfo.getuserId()];

Comment: String departmentPicklist = u.department__c;        
          
              System.debug('*** User : ' + u);
        
        RecordType rt = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE name = :departmentPicklist Limit 1];
        
        
      List<Contact>  con = [Select id,LastName,Name
               FROM Contact 
               WHERE RecordTypeId = : rt.Id];
       
              System.debug('*** con : ' + con );
        
        return con;
    }
 }

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and put the code in a block of its own (put 4 spaces at the beginning of each line that is code).  You'll have a much better chance of an answer if we can read the code.  It's certainly possible to have a Visualforce page that is selective about which records it displays.